# Saving output of scipy.stats.spearmanr() to excel or text

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, visualization, correlation

I need to produce correlation matrices that include both the test statistic and the p-value (this is really common practice in psychology research) and I'm using

```
spearmanr()
```

from scipy.stats to do this.

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
v_1    v_2    v_3    v_4    v_5
 1      4      2      5      3 
 5      3      6      2      4 
 6      2      4      1      1 
 2      5      3      2      6 
 6      3      2      2      3
```

when I call spearmanr() as

```
cor1 = spearmanr(v_1, v_4)
```

I can see the output in the console, and I can

```
print(cor1)
```

which returns

```
SpearmanrResult(correlation=array([[x,y,z,a,b,c]]), (pvalue=array([[x,y,z,a,b,c]]))
```

But I can't do anything with those values that allows me to lay them out for reporting in a style of my choosing.

I've tried converting them to a pandas DF with

```
cors = pd.DataFrame(cor1)
```

and I've tried to write it to excel or text with to_excel etc.

I'm missing something stupid.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cor1 is actually a NamedTuple. You can access the relevant fields: 
`cor1.correlation` and `cor1.pvalue`.

Alternatively you can decompose directly when calling spearman:

`cor, pvalue = spearmanr(v_1, v_4)`

These arrays can then be converted to DataFrames and written to excel.

e.g. `pd.DataFrame(cor).to_csv("correlation.csv")`

Comment: Thanks a million but when I try this exact code I get:
    <code>
    pd.DataFrame(cor).to_csv("correlation.csv")
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-24-7c10cdbde3e5>", line 3, in <module>
    pd.DataFrame(cor).to_csv("correlation.csv")

    File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 422, in     
    __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

    ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
    <\code>

I have made sure the arguments relate to my actual data set.

Comment: @KevOMalley743 Well for the example input you are calling it for two vectors and will get back a single value for the correlation and pvalue. You can't create a dataframe from that. Given that you are calculating spearman for multidimensional data and hence get back arrays for correlation and pvalus it will work fine. See here for some examples: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html

Comment: That second comment really helped, thank you so much for taking the time. It seems strange to me that pythonists think about visualising correlations so differently. I've been using spss for years and want to get away from it, but I will say that even though python is way better for data cleaning, spss still has some better functionality.